# Upgrade package dependencies using Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I have [a script](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle/blob/3ebeabe624a2d766cff5b128146471fe99a91eba/misc/Upgrade.hs) that deploys a Haskell program once a day. It currently does:

```
cabal update
cabal install --only-dependencies
cabal configure
cabal build
```

Which ensures it has the latest package index list, upgrades any dependency whose lower bound in the `project.cabal` has changed, and builds the code.

However, I'd really like to upgrade any dependency that has a new suitable version.

- I tried adding `--upgrade-dependencies` but that refused to upgrade anything because it would break existing packages.
- I tried combining that with `--force-reinstalls`, but it installed a new version of `template-haskell` (not a good idea) and things like `QuickCheck` would no longer compile.

What is the right way to upgrade packages automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Cabal 2.0.0.0 or above.

From Cabal 2.0.0.0 it no longer upgrades `template-haskell`, as per [the changelog](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/898fcc230fb537064f0992cfffb5955b6bc36d34/cabal-install/changelog#L121):

> - Made the 'template-haskell' package non-upgradable again ([#4185](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/4185)).

So `--upgrade-dependencies --force-reinstalls` works with newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cabal new-build` and if you only want to upgrade *most* dependencies then freeze the few you wish to hold constant in a cabal.project.freeze file.

```
cat <<EOF >cabal.project.freeze
constraints: template-haskell == 2.13.0.0
EOF
```

And

```
cabal update
# Perhaps rm -rf dist-newstyle if you want a completely fresh build
cabal new-build --upgrade-dependencies
```